# MVC, uploading CSV, int.Parse(), "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parsing, parseint

I know that this has been asked before and I have tried my best to find an answer that could help me with my problem - but with no succes. I apoligize for the duplicated question but I hope you still want to help me out.

Thanks in advance!

I have made a solution where I can upload a csv file into my sql database. When I run the code, choose the file and presses "Upload" I get the following error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

The error is being thrown in my controller at; **LearningNumbers.LearningNumberId = int.Parse(values[0]);**

**My CSV**

```
LearningNumberId;Note;Activity;Price
1;Node1;her er node 1;22
2;Node1;her er node 2;33
```

**My model:**

```
namespace MTH_SQL.Model
{
    public class LearningNumberRecord
    {
        [Key]
        public int LearningNumberId { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public string Activity { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**My controller:**

```
namespace MTHoejgaard.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private MTHoejgaardContext db = new MTHoejgaardContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase File)
    {
        if (File != null && File.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            StreamReader csvReader = new StreamReader(File.InputStream);
            {
                string inputLine = "";
                while ((inputLine = csvReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] values = inputLine.Split(new Char[] { ';' });
                    LearningNumberRecord LearningNumbers = new LearningNumberRecord();
                    LearningNumbers.LearningNumberId = int.Parse(values[0]);  // <-- IT THROWS THE ERROR HERE
                    LearningNumbers.Note = values[1];
                    LearningNumbers.Activity = values[2];
                    LearningNumbers.Price = int.Parse(values[3]);
                    db.LearningNumbers.Add(LearningNumbers);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                csvReader.Close();
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    } 
}
```

My View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="File" id="File" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" />
    <span>@ViewBag.Message</span>
}
```

Comment: I guess if you debugged your code you would find the answer in one minute. Does it help to remove the first line from the CSV file - or - to jump the first line when parsing the file?

Comment: I actually did try to debug it but I still have a lot to learn so I might have missed that.
And yes - it helped to either delete the first line or jump it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSV file to this (first line removed):

```
1;Node1;her er node 1;22
2;Node1;her er node 2;33
```

Alternatively, jump the first line when parsing the file.

Comment: This is rather embarrassing! Thank you so much - this did the trick!